# Setting up iBeacon actions and monitoring from Appdelegate

Tags: bluetooth, monitoring, viewcontroller, ibeacon, appdelegate

I am making an app that has multiple views. I want it to be able to monitor for beacons in the background of all the views. So, I am setting up the code in the App delegate. When the code is in the app delegate, it does nothing. If I move it to the first view controller to load, it will ask for Authorization to use location but doesn't perform actions when entering the beacon region. Here is the code in the app delegate. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }



    func applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(_ application: UIApplication) {


        let beaconManager = CLLocationManager()


            var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

            var window: UIWindow?


            locationManager = CLLocationManager()

            locationManager.delegate = self

            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

            func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
                if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
                    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                        if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {

                            startScanning()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            func startScanning() {

                let uuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "2F234454-CF6D-4AOF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")
                let beaconRegion1 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid as! UUID, major: 0, minor: 1, identifier: "AuschwitzAlbum")
                let beaconRegion2 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid as! UUID, major: 0, minor: 2, identifier: "Children")

                locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion1)
                locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion2)
            }


            func beaconManager(manager: Any, didEnterRegion: CLBeaconRegion) {

                switch CLBeaconRegion() {

                case beaconRegion1:
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "exhibitions")
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


                case beaconRegion2: break

                default: break

                }
            }

    }


func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Comment: When the app enters a beacon region, it is supposed to display a view stating "You have entered XXX region. Would you like to see the exhibits about XXX?" If they tap yes, it will take them to the appropriate view. If they tap no, it will simply close the view.

Comment: It may be more interesting to create your own singleton rather than overriding with too much code the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To more easily get started, you could try to move the call to `startScanning()` outside the nested conditions or use the debugger to see if the enter and exit region part of your code actually gets called.

Here is some simplified sample code to get you started:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    let beaconRegion1 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "2F234454-CF6D-4AOF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")!, identifier: "AuschwitzAlbum")

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        requestLocationAuthorization()
        return true
    }

    // Standard AppDelegate implementations here
}

extension AppDelegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func requestLocationAuthorization() {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            startMonitoringRegion()
        }
    }

    func startMonitoringRegion() {
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion1)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Did enter region \(region.identifier)")
        if region.identifier == beaconRegion1.identifier{
            showViewController()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Did exit region \(region.identifier)")
    }

    func showViewController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "exhibitions")
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```